# calling the component from within the script

Tags: apache-flex, custom-component

I have a component and I want to call it from within the script section.

So instead of just getting it like this:

```
<s:application>
<script>
</script

<ns1:msns includeIn="login" x="482" y="541">
    </ns1:msns>
</s:application>
```

I want to have it something like this:

```
<s:application>
<script>
protected function mmshakkoutab(event:MouseEvent):void
            {               
var ns1:msns:component = new component();
ns1:msns.x = 5
ns1:msns.x = 5
}
</script

</s:application>
```

Is this even possible? I have searched around but all examples give me the component in the place under the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly, then yes, this is possible.  You're terminology of "call a component" is non-standard; but I think you want to create the component in ActionScript instead of MXML.  Anything you can do with MXML you can do with ActionScript.

You have the right idea; and you're almost all of the way there; there are just a few things I would change.  First, in ActionScript you would import the class; you wouldn't reference the MXML namespace, conceptually like this:

```
import com.myPackage.msns;
```

In your script block.

When you create the component, you want to create a variable that points to it.  This would correspond to the id field in MXML.  Your syntax of `ns1:msns:component` will probably cause compiler errors.  But, you can create the component like this:

```
var msns :component = new component()
```

I'll mention here that usual convention is to capitalize component names.  Your use of lowercase is not syntactically wrong, though.

Then set the properties on the component, which you're already doing:

```
msns.x = 5
msns.x = 5
```

And finally--this is the step you're missing--you must add the new component to a container.  You can do that with [addElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Group.html#addElement%28%29) if you're dealing with Spark containers or [addChild](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29) if you're dealing with MX containers.  Since, in the example you provided you're parent container is the spark Application, I'll use addElement:

```
this.addElement(msns);
```

So, you're code block would be re-written like this:

```
protected function mmshakkoutab(event:MouseEvent):void{               
 var msns:component = new component();
 msns.x = 5
 msns.x = 5
 this.addElement(msns);
}
```

One thing you should consider reading up on is the [Flex Component LifeCycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7fff.html).  Every Flex component goes through it; and certain things are done in a certain order for a certain purpose. For creating Children you may be better off extending createChildren(), especially if you want the component created as part of the initial setup of your application tag.

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically instantiate the component instead of a declarative implementation, use `addElement()` to add components to the display list.

For example, to add a visual element to a Spark Group named `container`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var component:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
                component.x = 5;
                component.y = 5;

                container.addElement(component);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Group id="container" />

</s:Application>
```

Within script blocks, use package namespaces instead of MXML namespaces.

```
import com.msns.Component;

var component:Component = new Component();
component.x = 5
```

Comment: I gotta +1 this even though we were writing our respective answers at the same time. :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give it a try the first thing when I'll arrive at work tomorrow :D

Answer (score 0):

if suppose your component is ActionScript i.e. extended to  sprite you can do like this

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var yourASClassObj:ASClass = new ASClass();

    var component:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
    this.addElement(component);

    component.addChild(yourASClassObj);
}
```